# how to move images to sdcard in android

Tags: android

In my android app i have an png image in asset folder as well as drawable folder. Recently i added sd card to my android emulator, that added successfully but i dont know how to move image in my sd card.

Is their any tutorial available ?

I am  using android 2.3.3 , and i have the sd card of 250mb as well.

Comment: what do you want to move? the images from your drawable or asset folder? Why do you want to do that? Or do you want to move your whole app to the SD card? Could you explain that more detailed?

Comment: any one of the both is fine, i want a png image in my sdcard thats it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eclipse you can see a DDMS icon on the top right corner, please click it now you can see the DDMS perspective in that you can lot of tabs now click on file explorer there you can see lot of folder, now you have to add the images in the sdcard folder.. It will work